# how to execute "select" statement inside Perl script using LIKE keyword?

Tags: sql-server, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
$a="test";

$DSN = q/dbi:ODBC:SQLSERVER/;
$uid = q/ivr/;
$pwd = q/ivr/;

$DRIVER = "Freetds";
$dbh = DBI->connect($DSN,$uid,$pwd) or die "Coudn't Connect SQL";

$sql_query1 = "select top(1) * from winast_sms_template where sms_tmp_service_id =1 and sms_tmp_name like '\%$a'";

$sql_address = $dbh->prepare($sql_query1);
$sql_address->execute();

while ((@city_address)=$sql_address->fetchrow_array())
       {
       $b = $city_address[2];
       print $b;
       }
```

Whenever i execute the program i doesn't get the right output and code execute successfully

please help me.

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: Don't try to interpolate variables in SQL queries with the DBI module. Use placeholders, like the documentation says. Also, `use strict; use warnings;` is a vital piece of your code that you left out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$sql_query1 = "select top(1) * from winast_sms_template where sms_tmp_service_id =1 and sms_tmp_name like ?";

$sql_address = $dbh->prepare($sql_query1);
$sql_address->execute('%' . $a);
```

Comment: `+` is not the concatenation operator in perl. You want period `.`.

Comment: My mistake; mixed my SQL & my perl.